# Flagged two garbage posts, were deleted, got banned for flagging them

Tags: discussion

[Scale up small bitmap pixel perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249151/scale-up-small-bitmap-pixel-perfectly/46249224#46249224)

[image]

The first two were deleted for the reason I gave. They are by the same poster in the same thread but are obvious garbage and unrelated to the question but I was banned from flagging. What sense does this make?

I don't understand what is meant by using the standard flagging. To me, an obvious garbage (or even spam) post needs to be handled immediately or someone like that first time poster will continue on for, potentially, hours or days till a mod gets to handling it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you flag banned or review banned?

Comment: @rene It says I'm banned from flagging

Comment: @Rob umm... can't be changed manually, but it says "Will be unbanned in 2 hours" from what I can see...

Comment: well, I don't see how your review action got you in a flag ban but without extra context I have to leave this to the puppy ... I mean the mods.

Comment: You custom flagged those two answers with "Garbage, weird post"... A rude/abusive would be fine there... Heck, even an NAA if you weren't that sure about it... but relying on a mod to get around to handling that custom flag might take a while and keep those posts hanging around longer. Red flags go to the top of the mod queue so we can get around to them asap and enough of them can result in community deletion without a mod. NAA flagging would have put it in community review as well... All in all - that didn't need a custom flag...

Comment: @JonClements So I understand the disagreement but getting banned for it? I considered "abusive" meaning someone went off on someone else when tied in with "rude".

Comment: @Rob yeah... that's a bit annoying... sometimes if we handle a load of flags in one go and you happen to have a lot pending that we go through, it sometimes happens that the percentage declined hits the percentage threshold of the most you're allowed to have declined in the last N many handled flags...

Comment: Looks like what'd pushed you over the threshold was the rest of your declined flags - you might want to review https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/162698?group=1&status=3

Comment: @JonClements I only had one other declined flag in the last seven days.

Comment: I would add that if you use a custom flag tell the mod what you expect them to do. Saying: *garbage, weird post* is just an observation they either agree or disagree with. Instead you have to explain what you want them to do that you can't. For example: *This is a garbage post that can be deleted. This user posted the same garbage here [link] so it is pretty abusive by now. Maybe the user need to be stopped/warned before posting more of this.*

Comment: The flag ban calculation is brain dead; [it triggers on the time the flags are _handled_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277475/declined-in-the-last-7-days-confusingly-appears-to-list-only-flags-cast-in-the#comment898967_277475), not the time they are cast.

Answer (score 28):

You custom flagged both of these posts as

> Garbage, weird post

I declined these with

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags

There is no reason either of these posts required a custom flag. In fact, other members of the community had already flagged these as "Not an answer" and the posts were on the way to deletion via [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17348892) from the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17348923). Use the standard flags for this, so that moderators can focus their attention on problems the community can't resolve.

Comment: The reason I used a custom flag is because I considered this higher priority. A poster who was obviously causing disruption in an inappropriate way that was neither rude nor abuse toward a poster (which was my understanding of that flag). As I type this, I don't recall if there is even a spam flag but I don't consider it spam either.

Comment: @Rob Rubbish posts like these which are clearly intended to be disruptive/trolling are fine to flag with rude/abusive.

Comment: Wow... did Rob talking to Rob just make me do a double take... :)

Comment: _"You didn't put the right label on this piece of garbage, so instead of zapping it, I left it for other people to pick up by hand."_

Comment: @Josh except it did get zapped... just with a note to say: "okay, we came out and looked, but next time, just put it in the bin that's there - you don't need us to come around and do it for you"...

Comment: The answers [were deleted by four reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17348923), not by a moderator, @JonClements.

Comment: @Josh yes... because of using standard flags it got put into queues and zapped... if the custom flag was the only one - it'd only have come to notice to a mod when they came around to it in the queue. And because it's a custom flag, we still have to look at it even if what needs to be done is already done (in which case - you've got the wrong/more people looking at it than needs be)

Comment: Right, you had to go out and look anyways, so even if you're going to decline the flag -- which I understand, more or less -- **why not take one extra click and remove the obvious trash** with your moderator zap rather than leaving it for "more people looking at it than needs be", i.e., the four reviewers.